# X and Y axes don't move after upgrading to TMC2100 drivers

Tags: stepper-driver, y-axis, x-axis, tmc2100

I had noisy DRV8825 drivers for my extruder E0 and X, Y, Z axes. I upgraded all to LV8729 drivers but they were still noisy, so I bought two TMC2100 drivers for the X and Y axes and two LV8729 for the Z axis and extruder E0. I updated Marlin (reversing endstops logic and choosing driver types) and I removed the jumpers under the driver pins. But my X and Y axis don't move; eventually the printer halts.
What could be wrong?

[image: TMC2100 driver]

Comment: Enough that this question makes little sense. Did you only upgrade them? As in: The cabling is unchanged? You will need to provide not a photo of the driver, but the code for the relevant settings in marlin for us to even think of answering this.

Comment: I found the problem. I'm going to answer my own question.

Comment: Looking forward to read what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps/unit also must be modified. In my case these values made the printer run silent and smooth.

```
#define DEFAULT_AXIS_STEPS_PER_UNIT   { 100, 200, 6160, 884 }
```

I set Max feed rate and Max acceleration as below:

```
#define DEFAULT_MAX_FEEDRATE          { 300, 300, 5, 25 }
#define DEFAULT_MAX_ACCELERATION      { 300, 300, 100, 10000 }
```